# Create a Google pull task queue from Java console application

Tags: task-queue

I'm not clear about how to create a pull queue in GCP from an outside application. I've found documentation about pulling messages but not about creating queues. 
Can somebody point me out some information about it?

Best Regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Creating queues from outside of an AppEngine App is currently not available.

Queue management features are coming in the new Cloud Tasks API, which is available in Alpha. You can request to join the Alpha [here](https://docs.google.com/forms/d/1g6yRocQ3wtdTArfO4JX8DoqOhYmsoTVgrlFnS0mV1bo/viewform?edit_requested=true)